# Prevent Rcpp from creating wrappers in RcppExports.R for non-exported functions

Tags: r, rcpp, roxygen2

I am developing an `R` package with `Rcpp` (v1.0.5), and trying to document some internal-only functions that will not be exposed to `R`. For example:

```
//' Some function
//' 
//' @param n input
//' @return a vector
//' @keywords internal
std::vector<int> foo(int n) {
  std::vector<int> v(n);
  
  return v;
}
```

However, even without the `@export` or `[[Rcpp::export]]` tags, running `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` still creates an entry in `RcppExports.R`:

```
#' Some function
#' 
#' @param n input
#' @return a vector
#' @keywords internal
NULL
```

This seems fine, but `devtools::document()` now complains for some reason:

```
...
Writing NAMESPACE
Warning: [SomePath\RcppExports.R:1] @title Missing name
...
```

The warning message can be circumvented by adding a `@noRd` tag to `foo()`, but I wonder if it's nessary in the first place. Is it possible to prevent `Rcpp` from creating the `NULL` entry at all? Or what is a good practice in this circumstance?

Comment: But why are you trying to document an unexported function? Who is the documentation for? If the function isn't exported then it shouldn't be included in the R level documentation at all. If only you or another developer will see it then why not just use code comments?

Comment: Rcpp does not create the `NULL`.  That is entirely done by `roxygen2::roxygenize`.  And if you don't want the entry created, _just do not write its part in your sources_.

Comment: @AllanCameron They were intended for other developers. The use of roxygen style is to make the documentation to appear more consistent across the project. But indeed a better practice seems to be simply using the regular comments.

Comment: Just break the regexp pattern, i.e don't use `#' ...` in R, use an extra spac `# ' ...`. Same for C++: turn `//' foo` into `// ' foo` and then `roxygen2` will leave it alone.

Comment: Just removing the tickmark also works but I sometimes move then in and out and it is a simple reminder ...